# find file with numeric values greater than a specified number

Tags: regex, find, ls

When I run the following command, I get a list of files

```
find . -type f -name '*_duplicate_[0-9]*.txt'

./prefix_duplicate_001.txt 

./prefix_duplicate_002.txt 

./prefix_duplicate_003.txt 

./prefix_duplicate_004.txt 

./prefix_duplicate_005.txt
```

Now I'm only interested in files which have the numbers greater than or equal to 003. How can I get this done?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `-regex` option in `find`, you can tweak regex to get all files with `3` or higher value after `_duplicate_` with leading zeroes:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -type f \
       -regex '.*_duplicate_0*([3-9]|[1-9][0-9])[0-9]*\.txt'
```

On OSX use this `find`:

```
find -E . -type f -regex '.*_duplicate_0*([3-9]|[1-9][0-9])[0-9]*\.txt'

./prefix_duplicate_003.txt
./prefix_duplicate_004.txt
./prefix_duplicate_005.txt
```

Comment: @anubhava somehow running those commands on my macbook gives me the following error "find: -regextype: unknown primary or operator"

Answer (score 0):

```
00[3-9]|(([1-9]\\d\\d)|(\\d[1-9]\\d))
```

only for the number part.

Comment: While code often speaks for itself, it's good to add some explanation to your code. This popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to.

Also, please apply proper formatting.

Comment: While code-only answers are not forbidden, please understand that this is a Q&A community, rather than a crowd-sourcing one, and that, usually, if the OP understood the code being posted as an answer, he/she would have come up with a similar solution on his/her own, and wouldn't have posted a question in the first place. The same principle applies further, to any future readers who might be unfamiliar with the code being presented. As such, please provide context to your answer and/or code by explaining *how* and/or *why* it works.

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern

```
.*_duplicate_(?!00[1-2])\d{3}\.txt
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/382)

Answer (score 0):

As much as I like to use single commands when possible, I think maybe this is what you need here:

```
find . -type f -name '*_duplicate_[0-9]*.mat' | awk -F '[_.]' '$4 > 3 { print $0 }'
```

There are variations on that - for example, this:

```
find . -type f -name "*.mat" | awk -F '[_.]' '$0 ~ /_duplicate_[0-9]*.mat/ && $4 > 3 { print $0 }'
```

But I'm not sure it really makes a difference from an efficiency standpoint...